# Use of xml config files - simple mapping approaches?

Tags: c, xml, config

I am writing a simple physics engine, and I want to include some form of config files.

As I look at xml, the tree structure makes a lot of sense to me, and looking at libxml it seems to be very easy to read and modify.

The problem I'm having is how I might impliment it.

My application is written in C, are there standard conventions for implementing xml config files?

For argument's sake I'll set up an example enviroment. Lets say I have a file called foo.c with a datastructure that looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
     char* name;
     float x;
     float y;
}info;
```

and a config file called foo.xml that looks like

```
<info>
    <name>something</name>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
</info>
```

and another class bar.c that reads xml files into trees using libxml2. How would do people normally populate such a data structure?

**I'M NOT ASKING FOR ALTERNATIVES TO XML**

example answer (something I've been thinking about but am not sure if this is the right way to implement).

bar.c has a functions:

```
tree* load_config(FILE* config_file);
char[][] get_fields(tree* current_tree);
```

you call that function, it returns a tree and then you have a bunch of conditionals like:

```
tree* current_tree = load_config(fopen("foo.xml"));
char[][] fields = get_fields(current_tree);

if( contains(fields, "name") ) {
    name = current_tree->name; //i'd have to navigate through the tree to find name or something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only needs config file and not necessarily XML, take a look on [Boost Program Options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/program_options.html)

It is simple and easy to use. It use the format of .ini file.

Example of .ini file:

```
[info]
name=something
x=0
y=0
```

Comment: But they might be better. XML is not massively complicated, but it is that little bit heavier to parse and deal with than it sounds like you need.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [libconfig](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/). In your case such a config file would be:

```
info {
    name = something;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
};
```

The Boost library is quite large in some distros (like Debian).

Answer (score 0):

i use the same things in same way but i use [libmxml](http://www.minixml.org/) library...its very simple